# JSLint : Unexpected ']' in array of object

Tags: javascript, jslint

I'm using JSLint in PHPStorm with ES6 and I have this error after the line : pathPublic + "/css/style.css",

> JSLint: Unexpected ']'.

My code :

```
    let filesCss = [
    {
        outputFilename: "fc-main.min.css",
        outputPath: pathPublic + "/css",
        inputFiles: [
            pathPublic + "/css/style.css",
        ],
    },
];
```

Comment: probably because you have commas after the last entry in the inputFiles array, after the last property in your object, and the last entry in the filesCss array

Comment: I tried to remove the 3 commas and it not works :/

Comment: @AndrewLohr That is perfectly legal. Trailing commas has been in ECMAScript since the beginning, with trailing commas in objects being supported since ES5.

Comment: @Birjolaxew legal or not, we're talking about JSLint errors and why the OP might of received that error from it.

Comment: @AndrewLohr Which means you should explain how to disable the error, or why it happens - not tell him to remove legal parts of his code with no explanation.

Comment: @Birjolaxew that is why I commented and did not post an answer. I gave him some advice that may work.

Answer (score 2):

The trailing commas can hisotrically give issues on older IE versions:

> The "Extra comma. (it breaks older versions of IE)" error (and the
>   alternative "Trailing comma" and "Unexpected ',' errors") are thrown
>   when JSLint, JSHint and ESLint encounter a comma following the final
>   element of an array literal or a comma following the final value in an
>   object literal. Since version 2.0.0 JSHint will only raise this
>   warning if the es3 option is set to true.

So you have to remove them or use the `es<version>` option:

```
    let filesCss = [
    {
        outputFilename: "fc-main.min.css",
        outputPath: pathPublic + "/css",
        inputFiles: [
            pathPublic + "/css/style.css"
        ]
    }
];
```

See: https://github.com/jamesallardice/jslint-error-explanations/blob/master/message-articles/extra-comma.md

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I remove the 3 commas, I have this error : "ESLint : Missing trailing comma. (comma-dangle)."

Comment: @ElGecko_76 Are you using ESLint or JSLint? It sounds like you're using both, with conflicting configs.

Comment: you just have to remove the `,` from `},`

Comment: Eslint, jshint, stylelint and JSlint. I have to delete one of the two?

Comment: I disabled JSLint in PHPStorm, I have kept the commas and I have no more errors. What are the linters that I have to use for javascript and css ? JSLint and Eslint are equivalents (competitors) ?

Comment: @ElGecko_76 You should only use one linter at a time for each language, and configure it to your needs. You're currently using 3 different linters for JS, with configurations that conflict.

Comment: Ah okay ! Which one is better between ESlint, JSHint and JSLint please ?

Comment: @ElGecko_76 That's completely a personal preference. If you're on a team, pick the one the team uses! ;^) If it's just you, quick 2¢ -- ESLint allows/requires you to turn on and off rules *until you're happy* with the ruleset. JSLint has one set of rules ([give or take](http://jslint.com/help.html#directives)), and is going to *tell you what to do, no questions allowed*. Personally, I like JSLint, but ESLint is probably more popular, as you can mold it to your specific use case. Either way, you probably owe Irvin an "Accepted" check for answering the original question. :^D

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanations :) . JSHint is also a lint ?